# Value not printing from inputs in UDF

Tags: python-3.x

Could I know what's missing in my UDF , my brain is fried atm and couldn't figure out what went wrong.

```
import math
import numpy as np

CoP = input("Enter the Value 1: ")
Po = input("Enter the Value 2: ")
Rf = input("Enter the Value 3: ")
Ti = input("Enter the Value 4: ")

def Total():
        Rf = Rf / 100
        Ti = Ti/ 12
        Total = CoP - (Po * np.e ** (-(Rf * Ti)))

        print(Total)
        return Total
```

~Brittany

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the global vars directly inside the method

Either pass the vars as arguments or declare the vars as global inside the method

**Edit~**: Converted the str to float

Method 1

```
import numpy as np

CoP = float(input("Enter the Value 1: "))
Po = float(input("Enter the Value 2: "))
Rf = float(input("Enter the Value 3: "))
Ti = float(input("Enter the Value 4: "))


def Total(CoP, Po, Rf, Ti):
    Rf = Rf / 100
    Ti = Ti / 12
    Total = CoP - (Po * np.e ** (-(Rf * Ti)))

    print(Total)
    return Total
Total(CoP, Po, Rf, Ti)
```

Method 2

```
CoP = float(input("Enter the Value 1: "))
Po = float(input("Enter the Value 2: "))
Rf = float(input("Enter the Value 3: "))
Ti = float(input("Enter the Value 4: "))


def Total():
    global CoP, Po, Rf, Ti
    Rf = Rf / 100
    Ti = Ti / 12
    Total = CoP - (Po * np.e ** (-(Rf * Ti)))

    print(Total)
    return Total
Total()
```

Comment: Thank you however the output still cant print.